# Angular 9 application "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays" error

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I am working on a Contacts app with Angular 9. I get a list of contacts via the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Contact } from '../models/Contact';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ContactsListService {

  contactsUrl = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=500&inc=name,location,email,cell,picture';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getContcts():Observable<Contact[]> {
    return this.http.get<Contact[]>(`${this.contactsUrl}`);
  }

}
```

The **Contacts List** component is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { ContactsListService } from '../../services/contacts-list.service';
import { Contact } from '../../models/Contact';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  contactsList:Contact[];

  constructor(private ContactsListService:ContactsListService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void  {
      this.ContactsListService.getContcts().subscribe(contactsList => {
        this.contactsList = contactsList;
      });

  }
}
```

Trying to iterate the contacts list this way

```
<ul *ngFor="let contact of contactsList">
    <li>{{contact.name.first}}</li>
</ul>
```

throws the error: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays`.

That very likely means `contactsList` is not an array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check the response you are getting from your API. It returns an object with "info" and "results" as keys.

Comment: `console.log(typeof this.contactsList);` returns an object.

Comment: typeof would anyway return an Object for both an Array or an Object, you would need to log, `this.contactList` to see the actual content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL is returning an object of the form

```
{
  results: [],
  info: {}
}
```

Use RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) to map the `results` obtained from the API.

Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Contact } from '../models/Contact';

export class ContactsListService {
  contactsUrl = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=500&inc=name,location,email,cell,picture';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getContcts():Observable<Contact[]> {
    return this.http.get<Contact[]>(`${this.contactsUrl}`)
      .pipe(map(response => response['results']));
  }
}
```

Assign empty array to `contactsList` on declaration.

Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { from } from 'rxjs';

import { ContactsListService } from '../../services/contacts-list.service';
import { Contact } from '../../models/Contact';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  contactsList: Contact[] = []; // assign empty array

  constructor(private ContactsListService:ContactsListService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void  {
    this.ContactsListService.getContcts().subscribe(
      contactsList => { this.contactsList = contactsList; },
      error => { // always good practice to handle error when subscribing to HTTP observables }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the error: `error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?`.

Comment: I overlooked you had a service. I've updated the whole answer. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: You need to import `map`. Notice the new import statements at the beginning of the service file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the endpoint 'https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=500&inc=name,location,email,cell,picture' does not return an array. To check it you may open it in the browser, or check in the network tab of the chrome developers tools while your app running